# Single number to represent a ratio?

Tags: statistics, soft-question

There's probably a very simple answer to this, but I can't put my finger on it.

I have two numbers.  I want one to be large, and the other to be small.  I'd like to identify these with a single value.

For instance (hypothetical example follows), students should have high test scores and low absence rates.  Therefore, a student with a test score of 100 and an absence rate of 0 is the ideal student.

For the purpose of this example, the absence rate is the more important number. We'd rather have a student with a test score of 50 and has an absence rate of 1 than a student with a test score of 100 and an absence rate of 2.  In other words, it's most important that the small number is actually small.

So taking `test score / absence rate` won't work.  Because in the aforementioned example, it scores both students equally.  Additionally, a student with perfect attendance throws a divide-by-zero error.

Any suggestions?  *Is* there actually a simple answer?  I apologize if the question is too elementary for this site.

Thanks!

P.S. I couldn't identify an appropriate tag, so please re-tag if you can think of a better one.

EDIT: Reading through my question, I see that it could depend on *how much more important* the small number is than the big number.  Really, I'm not concerned with the particulars.  A general answer is all I need to craft a solution to my specific problem.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a function like $f(x,y)=xe^{-y}$, which is linearly increasing in $x$ for fixed $y$, and exponentially decreasing in $y$ for fixed $x$.

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhat of an "ad-hoc" answer, drawn from experience with weighted grading, etc.

**Attendance**: You may want to *subtract* absence rate from 100, e.g., so high scores uniformly express desirability, with 100, e.g., "perfect".  In doing so, you could simply subtract "attendance rate" from 100 (so a student attending 24 of 25 classes would have a score of 96), or 2. you could assign a "point penalty" for every class missed, which gets subtracted from 100 possible attendance "points".  In that sense, say there are 50 classes in all, and a student attends only 25 of 50 classes.  By the initial attendance rate (1), the student would receive an attendance score of "50"; whereas, if you penalize students 4 points for each missed class, that student would receive no attendance credit. I.e. you can establish a minimum threshold where students do not receive "any" attendance credit unless they attend more than 50% of the classes.

**Test Score**:

- Average the test scores to calculate average test score (for maximum 100 score).  Four tests at $100$ points each would thereby each contribute $25$%, or $25$ possible points, to the total test score (of course, if you have 3 tests, it would probably be "nicer" arithmetically speaking to add all of a students test scores, then divide by number of tests.

  - You can also weight particular exams, like a final:  E.g. You could give more weight to the final exam:  $2$ midterms ($100$ points possible, for each) and $1$ final exam (200 points possible, or $100$ doubled), add, and then divide by 4, to arrive at a test score, with $100$ the maximum score.
  - You could also simply break up the $100$ maximum test score by assigning, for example, $40$ possible points for final, $20$ possible points for each of two midterms, and $5$ points for each of $4$ quizzes.
  - Total score: If you now have decided on a means to rate attendance, with maximum score $100$, and the same for test score, you then need only assign a "weight" factor of greater than 1 to multiply by $100$ to arrive at the weighted attendance score: sum test score* $:= T$ with the weighted attendance score $:= A$, and divide by "$F$",( 1 + "the weight factor you chose for attendance"), and you'll have a single score, with highest possible score @ 100.

---

E.g.: Suppose you consider a students attendance rate to be *twice* as important as his/her test score.

Then in this case $F = 2$. $T$ is the test score, and $A = 2 \times\;\;$ attendance rate.  Then compute: $\displaystyle \text{Final Score} = \frac{(T + A)}{F} = \frac{T + A}{1 + 2} = \frac {T+A}{3}$

Comment: The use of students and tests was entirely hypothetical, but your answer is very informative notwithstanding.  Thank you very much for helping so thoroughly.

Comment: In my real-world problem, what I exemplified by "absence rate" is actually the standard deviation for a sequence of values (I simplified things for the purpose of easy explanation).  I like how you determined a "score" for absence... but how would you suggest doing the same for standard deviation?

I suppose the minimum standard deviation is 0, and the maximum is equal to half of the range?